# Null Pointer Exception for RawQuery sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

In my activity in want to pass Title Name to check it in sqlite database if title is there then return "Can't use" else "can use". But some thing wrong with my database, i m getting  "null pointer Exception". Can u help me because i'm new .Thank you

this is my code in activity

```
//check title name 
BookEntry title = db.getTitle(str);
    if(title == null){
        Toast.makeText(context, title.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(context, title.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

this is my code in database solution

```
//get title name where = str
public BookEntry getTitle(String str){
    BookEntry book = null;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT title FROM " +
    BooksDBHelper.TABLE_BOOK + " WHERE "
        +BooksDBHelper.KEY_TITLE + " = ? ", 
        new String[]{str});

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount()!=0){
        book = new BookEntry();
        book.setTitle("can't use");
    }else{
        book.setTitle("can use");
    }
    return book;

}
```

this is logcat error

```
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889): java.lang.NullPointerException
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at mutitablesql.db.BooksDB.getTitle(BooksDB.java:90)
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at mainactvity.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:112)
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
 12-28 15:06:46.016: E/AndroidRuntime(9889):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: it's allrigth brother

Comment: where null pointer coming debug and tell us

Comment: where ur getting null pointer exception ? post log

Comment: please check it again in my edit question

Comment: @user3001046 please up vote the ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if title is null. title.getTitle obviously null pointer exception
if(title == null){
    Toast.makeText(context, title.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

book is not innitialed for else

```
if(cursor.getCount()!=0){
    book = new BookEntry();
    book.setTitle("can't use");
}else{
    book.setTitle("can use");
}
```

with this code line of logcat getTitle is failing.

```
at mutitablesql.db.BooksDB.getTitle(BooksDB.java:90)
```

Comment: This is true but does not explain the stacktrace. There are multiple problems in the code...

Comment: @laalto but as per user he is saying db is good.

Answer (score 0):

At least here is one possible NPE:

```
BookEntry book = null;

//...

if(cursor.getCount()!=0){
    book = new BookEntry();
    book.setTitle("can't use");
}else{
    book.setTitle("can use");
}
```

In the else branch, `book` is `null`.

Your question title suggests the NPE has something to do with `rawQuery()`. The code snippet does not show how you initialize `db` you use in `getTitle()`, it's possibly `null` as well. Note there are two potential scopes for `db` - in the first one it's non-null (as you say in the comments) because you're able to call `db.getTitle()` without NPE but it's a different story inside `getTitle()`.